# Form validation bootstrap 3. Обращение к select multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, валидация

Здравствуйте.

Делаю валидацию формы и на толкнулся на проблему из `select`. [Использую вот этот плагин для валидации формы](http://formvalidation.io/examples/).

```
 <select name="type_adver[]" class="form-control" multiple>                              
    <option value="1">Салон массажа</option>                                                                         
    <option value="2">Салон эротического массажа</option>                                                                        
    <option value="3">Частное лицо</option>                                                                  
    <option value="4">Частное лицо эро массаж</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
</select>
```

Если имя "type_adver", то все работает а если "type_adver[]" то не работает

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bootstrapSelectForm')
        .find('[name="type_adver"]')
            .selectpicker()
            .change(function(e) {
                $('#bootstrapSelectForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'type_adver');
            })
            .end()

        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            excluded: ':disabled',
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                type_adver: {
                    validators: {
                        callback: {
                            message: 'Выберете одну категорию',
                            callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                                // Get the selected options
                                var options = validator.getFieldElements('type_adver').val();
                                return (options != null && options.length >= 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
 });
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Замените ключ:

fields: {
                type_adver: {
...
}}

на 

fields: {
                'type_adver[]': {
...
}}

и

getFieldElements('type_adver')

на 

getFieldElements('type_adver[]')

поможет?

Comment: Помогло спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bootstrapSelectForm')
    .find('[name="type_adver[]"]')
        .selectpicker()
        .change(function(e) {
            $('#bootstrapSelectForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'type_adver[]');
        })
        .end()

    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            'type_adver[]': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Выберете одну категорию',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the selected options
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('type_adver[]').val();
                            return (options != null && options.length >= 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

});